# Why is the melting point of meta-diiodobenzene higher than that of ortho-diiodobenzene?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, halides, melting-point

I'm currently trying to reason for as why the melting point of meta-diiodobenzene higher than that of ortho-diiodobenzene and I'm unsure of what to say. I understand the para isomer has the highest melting point due to symmetry and packing efficiency and would also understand the reasoning **if** the ortho isomer melting point was higher than the meta melting point (due to possible greater dipole moment and dipole dipole interactions), but the only reasoning I currently have is that there is some orbital overlap or hinderence between the iodine atoms which negate these effects? Please can someone help me... maybe it's something to do with the mesmoric or resonance effects (which I have little understanding of), many thanks

Comment: If you have little understanding of mesomeric effects then maybe concentrate on that. Trying to analyse melting points (and other random values) may be enticing, but in practice quickly becomes a waste of time.

Comment: Melting point is not a thing to be explained by such qualitative arguments. (Boiling point is a different story altogether.)

Comment: First off, what actually are the melting points? They may not both be known; Sigma-Aldrich fails to give one in the SDS for its ortho compound.

Comment: According to https://www.stenutz.eu/chem/solv6.php?name=m-diiodobenzene and https://www.stenutz.eu/chem/solv6.php?name=o-diiodobenzene the MPs are 40C and 27C respectively. So the same at this level of handwaving